# Perfect square and odd prime divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that the number of distinct remainders which occur when perfect square is divided by an odd prime $p$ is $\frac{p+1}{2}$. I expressed the square number using Euclid's lemma of division but I could not arrive at the proof

Comment: Do you mean: of the $p$ possible remainders possible mod $p$, show that only $(p+1)/2$ occur?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $x^2$ and $y^2$ have the same remainder when divided by $p$ if and only if $p$ divides $x^2-y^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the numbers $1^2,2^2, \ldots, (p-1)^2$ observe that $i^2 \equiv (p-i)^2 \pmod{p}$. So if you reduce this list modulo $p$ you will get only $\frac{p+1}{2}$ distinct residue classes.

Comment: But how do you know that $1^2\not\equiv a^2$ or some $a$ other than $1,p-1$? All you've shown currently is an upper bound. You haven't used that $p$ is prime...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you are right about the upper bound. I made an assumption that the OP would have ideas about $x \to x^2$ being an injective map in mod $p$ (since $p$ is odd).

Comment: It's not an injective map, by your very argument...

Comment: my mistake: injective when you restrict the sequence to $1^2,2^2, \ldots , (p-1/2)^2$